# what should be used HashMap or HashSet?

Tags: java, collections

If you are given a set of records (say, User records with `Id`, `Name` and `age` fields) and you need to send a collection of it
to the view for simple traversal. Then which collection would be preferable for use between `HashMap` and `HashSet`
and why? What hashcode generation code would you use in the User class for efficiency?

Comment: If you are not happy with these answers, update the question to make it clear what you really want to know and/or add comments.  Do not simply repost the question.  Your repost will be down-voted and closed, and you will lose reputation points.

Answer (score 1):

A `HashSet` is in itself an implementation of the `HashMap` so in the end it does not really make much of a difference. However, since you are dealing with users, I think that eventually you will need to access `User` objects by ID.

Assuming that each user has a unique ID, you could use a `HashMap` with ID's as a key and the entire `User` object as value. This will allow you to both traverse and access specific user data.

Comment: HashSet is not a implementation of HashTable but it implements Set<E> interface.

Comment: @ArunKumar: If you debug a `HashSet<K>` you will notice a structure such as this: `HashMap<K, Object>`. For every item you throw in the set, it adds it as a key to the `HashMap` and adds a dummy object as a value. When I said an implementation I was not referring to interfaces, just the internal workings of the `HashSet` class.

Comment: `HashSet` is not an implementation of `HashMap`. Even if you say that the `HashSet` uses an internal `HashMap` to store the data it is not an implementation instead a use association. If `HashSet` were an implementation of a `HashMap`, then you could have something like `HashMap x = new HashSet` and that's plain wrong.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: As per my last line in my response to Arun Kumar: *When I said an implementation I was not referring to interfaces, just the internal workings of the HashSet class*

Comment: First, in Java, a class X `extends` another class and `implements` one or more interfaces. Second, if `HashSet` implements the `Set` interface using an internal `HashMap`, that makes `HashMap` and `HashSet` having an **use** relationship, this does not neccesarily means that *one does not i̶m̶p̶l̶e̶m̶e̶n̶t̶s̶ extends another*. More about this [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html).

Answer (score 1):

HashMap and HahSet use diffrent data structure to store objects.

In a **HashMap** you store objects in **key-value** pairs

In a **HashSet** you store only the **keys** as objects.

---

**Following are some of the difference between them:**

---

1. HashSet is implementation of Set interface. **HashMap** is the implementation of Map interface.
2. HashSet Store only value. HashMap Stores data in form of key value
   pair.
3. HashSet does not allow duplicate values/objects HashMap allows
   duplicate value/objects but would not allow duplicate key.
4. HashSet is slower than hashmap. HashMap is faster than hashset
   because the values are associated to unique key
5. In HashSet, member object is used for calculating hashcode value
   which can be same for two objects so equal () method is used to
   check for equality if it returns false that means two objects are
   different.In HashMap, hashcode value is calculated using key object.